# How can I generate multiple random numbers?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new at JavaScript. I just finished a JavaScript course so I'm working on some projects I came up with myself. Also any advice outside of the question im asking is welcomed too. So I'm trying to generate multiple different random letter phrases ranging from 1 letter to 6 letters with the object but I cant figure out how to generate several. Im only able to do one phrase, Is there a way to do this, Im thinking with some kind of loop? Not sure, thanks

```js
const Words = {
  0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e',
  5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j',
  10: 'k', 11: 'l', 12: 'm', 13: 'n', 14: 'o',
  15: 'p', 16: 'q', 17: 'r', 18: 's', 19: 't',
  20: 'u', 21: 'v', 22: 'w', 23: 'x', 24: 'y', 25: 'z'
}

const phraseLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1)) + 1

const firstWord = Words[Object.keys(Words)[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(Words).length)]]

const secondWord = Words[Object.keys(Words)[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(Words).length)]]

const thirdWord = Words[Object.keys(Words)[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(Words).length)]]

const fourthWord = Words[Object.keys(Words)[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(Words).length)]]

const fifthWord = Words[Object.keys(Words)[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(Words).length)]]

const sixthWord = Words[Object.keys(Words)[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(Words).length)]]

const numberstudents = () => {}

const name = nameLength => {
  if (phraseLength === 1) {
    return firstWord
  } else if (phraseLength === 2) {
    return firstWord + secondWord
  } else if (phraseLength === 3) {
    return firstWord + secondWord + thirdWord
  } else if (phraseLength === 4) {
    return firstWord + secondWord + thirdWord + fourthWord
  } else if (phraseLength === 5) {
    return firstWord + secondWord + thirdWord + fourthWord + fifthWord
  } else if (phraseLength === 6) {
    firstWord + secondWord + thirdWord + fourthWord + fifthWord + sixthWord
  }
}

console.log(name(phraseLength))
```

Im fairly new at coding and this is my first time asking for any any kind of help on the internet. So once again thanks

Comment: General tip: using three backticks before and after your code formats it as code in Markdown (which is how StackOverflow formats posts). Also your `Words` is essntially an array, since it has number keys — it could just be an array instead (`['a', 'b', 'c',]` etc).

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways you could do this, but a simple method (if you're familiar with arrays) would be:

```js
// This is just a shortcut to generating an array of a-z
const alphabet = Array.from({ length: 26 }, (_, i) =>
  String.fromCharCode(97 + i))

const phraseLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 1 + 1)) + 1

const name = (nameLength) =>
  // Make an array with the length specified in the arg
  Array.from({ length: phraseLength }, (_) =>
    // Select letters at random from the array
    alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)])
    // Join the resultant array to a string
    .join('')

console.log(name(phraseLength))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Words = {
  0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd', 4: 'e',
  5: 'f', 6: 'g', 7: 'h', 8: 'i', 9: 'j',
  10: 'k', 11: 'l', 12: 'm', 13: 'n', 14: 'o',
  15: 'p', 16: 'q', 17: 'r', 18: 's', 19: 't',
  20: 'u', 21: 'v', 22: 'w', 23: 'x', 24: 'y', 25: 'z'
};

const generateRandomPhrase = length => {
  let phrase = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(Words).length);
    phrase += Words[randomIndex];
  }
  return phrase;
};

const numberstudents = () => {
  const numberOfPhrases = 5; // Change this to the desired number of phrases
  for (let i = 0; i < numberOfPhrases; i++) {
    const phraseLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    const randomPhrase = generateRandomPhrase(phraseLength);
    console.log(randomPhrase);
  }
};

numberstudents();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
Naming:
Changed the name from "Words" to letters as that is really what they 
are. Naming things is one of the hardest things to do, but good names 
allow us to think and reason more clearly.

Data type choice:
Use an Array rather than an Object, as Arrays already allow us to 
access a property by index. Also makes code cleaner and faster, with 
less Object.key() calls.
*/
const letters = [
  "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p",
  "q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"
];

/*
Encapsulation:
Use functions whenever you have operations that run repeatedly. We need 
to get a random number both to get the length of a phrase, and to pick
a random letter. We'll put that in a function, and call that function
instead. This allows us to run an operation repeatedly without hard 
coding it.
*/
function getRandomNumber(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
}

// The word generator could also be put in a function
function getRandomWords(words) {
  for (let i = 0; i < words; i++) {
    const wordLength = getRandomNumber(1, 6);
    let word = "";
    for (let j = 0; j < wordLength; j++) {
      word += letters[getRandomNumber(0, 26)];
    }
    console.log(word);
  }
}

getRandomWords(5); //logs 5 random words
```

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to decompose the problem into pieces (functions).

A "phrase" consists of "words", separated by a space. Let's accumulate them in an array and then `join` it:

```
function phrase() {
    let out = []
    let numWords = random(MIN_PHRASE_LEN, MAX_PHRASE_LEN + 1)

    for (let i = 0; i < numWords; i++)
        out.push(word())

    return out.join(' ')
}
```

Similarly, a "word" consists of "letters", so the code is almost exactly the same:

```
function word() {
    let out = []
    let numLetters = random(MIN_WORD_LEN, MAX_WORD_LEN + 1)

    for (let i = 0; i < numLetters; i++)
        out.push(letter())

    return out.join('')
}
```

A "letter" is just a random letter picked from the alphabet:

```
const LETTERS = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

function letter() {
    let letterIndex = random(0, LETTERS.length)
    return LETTERS[letterIndex]
}
```

The last piece is the `random` function which accepts two arguments `min` and `max` and is supposed to return a random integer `min <= N < max`.

Good luck!